# How do I find the highest amount of overlapping substrings in a line in python?

Tags: python, string, substring

I have the following string

`a = "AAWJBDJSDJBJSQQAAASDNDKSDKJSDKSJDDJKJSKJAAAAASKJDSJDKJSDKJDAAAAAAAA"`
 The first thing I do is count the A's in the line:

`a.count("A")` This works fine.

The next thing I want to do is find the value of the longest overlapping "A". In this case it would be AAAAAAAA (8 times).
So i want my output to be:
`The Longest polyA is 8`

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Do you want/expect the repeated substrings to begin with `A` or is that just an example, and `JB` might be another example?

Comment: No in this case I am only searching for multiple overlapping A's

Comment: A regex match for `A+` would __have__ to start earliest possible in the string to be the longest match. So references to ‘overlapping’ (and not-overlapping) are redundant. You just want the longest sequence of As in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the string, keeping track of the longest run:

```
a = "AAWJBDJSDJBJSQQAAASDNDKSDKJSDKSJDDJKJSKJAAAAASKJDSJDKJSDKJDAAAAAAAA"
longest = 0
cnt = 0
for c in a:
    if c == 'A':
        cnt += 1
    else:
        longest = max(longest, cnt)
        cnt = 0

longest = max(longest, cnt)
print(longest)
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is with regular expressions:

```
import re

string = "AAWJBDJSDJBJSQQAAASDNDKSDKJSDKSJDDJKJSKJAAAAASKJDSJDKJSDKJDAAAAAAAA"

print(len(max(re.findall('A+', string),key=len)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of doing this.

The first method uses regex and is easy to write. It's good enough for your case.

```
import re

string = "AAWJBDJSDJBJSQQAAASDNDKSDKJSDKSJDDJKJSKJAAAAASKJDSJDKJSDKJDAAAAAAAA"

print(len(max(re.findall('A+', string)))) # abusing the fact that longer strings are "larger"
```

The second method uses pattern matching and is complicated. Check out [this library](https://github.com/santinic/pampy) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the longest substring with a single character repeated - not overlapping.

The following function will find the longest substring with a single character repeated whether or not that character is "A".

```
def find_longest_substring(s):
    longest_substring = s[0]
    longest_length = 1
    substring = s[0]
    for e in s:
        if e == substring[0]:
            substring += e
            continue
        length = len(substring)
        if length > longest_length:
            longest_substring = substring
            longest_length = length
    return longest_substring


input_string = "AAWJBDJSDJBJSQQAAASDNDKSDKJSDKSJDDJKJSKJAAAAASKJDSJDKJSDKJDAAAAAAAA"
print(f"The longest PolyA is {find_longest_substring(input_string)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools.groupby()` with `max()` here:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a = "AAWJBDJSDJBJSQQAAASDNDKSDKJSDKSJDDJKJSKJAAAAASKJDSJDKJSDKJDAAAAAAAA"
>>> max(("".join(g) for _, g in groupby(a)), key=len)
AAAAAAAA
```